# SQL returning full objects (*) from distincted columns

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am looking for a solution concerning SQL Query for Oracle DB what returns DISTINCT **full** objects from many columns e.g:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mt.column1, mt.column2, mt.column3 FROM MyTable mt;
```

But I need full objects like `SELECT * FROM MyTable`

Is there any way to obtain such effect using usual SQL statements?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please update it to let us know what you want.

Comment: You can use "Group By mt.column1, mt.column2, mt.column3" . This may help if I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: @NikhilBatra, does Oracle really cheat when it comes to GROUP BY? (Like some other dbms products do...)

Comment: As far as I know oracle is the most honest and sincere DBMS following all the rules, so I can't call it a cheater :P

Comment: Are you looking to exclude rows which have `NULL` values in any of the table's columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mt.column1, mt.column2, mt.column3 ORDER BY mt.column1, mt.column2, mt.column3) As Seq
    FROM 
        MyTable mt) AS DT
WHERE
    Seq = 1;
```

Comment: [I think not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11206498/4519059) and you need to do it in other way ;).